# How safe is the Dominican Republic currently?

Tags: safety, event-based-effects, scams, dominican-republic

I'm leaving for a week in the Dominican Republic very soon in Punta Cana (as far east one can get from Haiti) and was concerned about the current unrest in Haiti spilling over and some horror stories I've read about all the swindlers and con artists there.  I travel to Mexico several times a year, but I'm bilingual and I know what states to avoid, plus I have lots of friends there, so I've never had any problems in that country.

Moreover, and no offense to anyone, but I've heard the phrase "Never trust a Dominican!" and yes I've heard that applied to other ethnicities, but I'd like some feedback on these topics.

My question is how safe is it overall right now? What are the common scams to be aware of?

Comment: I have been there a few years ago and stayed at two different resorts. I have not faced any issue. The first resort had a little office for a tour company and the guy there was fantastic, he was a white Dominican, and I faced no scams or anything like that. Even when I moved to the second resort I arranged everything with that guy. I have been to a lot of places in and around Punta Cana, I even rented a helicopter and visited an uninhabited Island, that guy arranged all of this. So, my advice, if you are staying in a resort, try to check if it has a tour company office, which I think it will.

Comment: One issue I had and I just remembered, the customs guy "stole" my perfume, which was within liquid limits (< 100 ml) but he insisted that it is more and he took it.

Comment: Where are you staying and what are you planning to do while you’re there? Wandering about on your own/being in local accommodation is very different to being mostly in a resort with some organised excursions. I came back 3 weeks ago from a week in an all-inclusive hotel, apart from the tour operator rep ‘persuading us’ that $30 was a small price to pay for a private taxi transfer instead of waiting for everyone else to clear Customs/luggage (it was), I didn’t notice anything other by way of scams than in other ‘holiday hotspot in poor-ish country’ resorts.

Comment: I'm staying at the resort, but I might check out a snorking trip or a catamaran ride.  All I'm planning to do is relax.  Work and personal life had been stressful lately.  No complaints, but I need to just lay out on the beach.

Comment: I'm not planning on talking to anyone much outside the resort.  The scams seem to start with that, like hey take my picture and they drop the camera and you buy a new, better one or the taxis want to charge you more than you would pay here in the states.  I get it, it's 59 pesos to the dollar there, Mexico was 18 my last trip, so if they can gouge the tourists that money goes a long way.

Comment: @James-JesseDrinkard don't begrudge them their over-charging too much. After all, you can afford a vacation in a place where many residents can barely afford to live. Just don't pay the 'whopper' they first try on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ‘safe’ is subjective depending on an individual’s risk appetite, while comprehensive advice on common scams is readily available in government travel advisories and many travel websites

Comment: @WeatherVane if people start paying more in developing nations, it will suddenly become more lucrative to travel to more developed locales instead, with the end result being less money for the country in question.

Comment: @JonathanReez what are you talking about? More lucrative for who? Tourists have always paid more than locals in developing nations. Nothing has just started.

Comment: @Traveller From [What is our stance on questions asking whether traveling to some area is safe?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8367/1810): "it is acceptable to ask about safety of an area".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Also from the question you linked: “The question needs to be such that it invites facts rather than opinions”. There’s plenty of official travel advice out there eg https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/dominican-republic Anything else is highly likely to be just anecdotal / opinion.

Comment: @Traveller True, but that invalidates your previous argument "I’m voting to close this question because ‘safe’ is subjective depending on an individual’s risk appetite".  Regarding your new argument, see [How to invite facts rather than opinions when asking whether traveling to some area is safe?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8675/1810)